# Select all rows in a KDB Table between two dates but only take the row with maximum value in a specific column

Tags: kdb

Day 1 on selecting data from KDB. 
I'd like to select all rows in table `quote_flat` for each unique value of `quote_id` but where only the max value of `ammendment_no`  is shown. Each quote_id as 1 to n `ammendment_no`. I'm only interest in the final (max) `ammendment_no`.

Sample Data

```
time                            quote_id    amendment_no
2019.08.14D23:15:40.353188000   188484088   1
2019.08.14D23:15:47.234021000   188484088   2
.
.
.
2019.08.14D23:15:47.234026000   188484088   25
```

Query returns:

```
2019.08.14D23:15:47.234026000   188484088   25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to:

```
select from quote_flat where ammendment_no=(max;ammendment_no) fby quote_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to use `fby`, the following statement will do what you're looking for:

```
select from quote_flat where amendment_no=(max;amendment_no)fby quote_id
```

https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/fby/
I think that it's also worth mentioning that using column names that contain special characters such as `quote_id` should be avoided as `_` is the cut/drop operator in kdb.

Comment: Technically `_` is not a problem character in symbols (and column names)